# 64bit arithmetic providing wrong output in 32-bit application

Tags: c, operating-system, cross-compiling, powerpc, endianness

I couldn't understand why the below identical operations reports two different outputs. When my num is declared to be of negative value and I add the num to the baseAddr, I see my addr going past 32-bit range. On the other hand, if I declare num to a positive value and do a subtraction, I do see the right result. i.e my resulting output is reported accurately. Can someone please explain what is wrong with the below computation?

```
/* Architecture is powerpc. Program cross-compiled for powerpc. Gcc Version- 4.6.2 */
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned long long u_int64;
typedef unsigned long u_int32;

int main() {
   u_int64 baseAddr = 0x8e008128;
   u_int32 num = -360;
   u_int64 addr = baseAddr + num;
   printf("\nAddr 1st step = 0x%llx\n", addr);

   /* Same operation, but slightly different */
   num = 360;
   addr = baseAddr - num;
   printf("\nAddr 2nd step = 0x%llx\n", addr);
   return 0;
}

/* Output:
Addr printed is 0x18e007fc0, but I need just 0x8e007fc0
/diagsk10copy/bin # ./e500GPR

Addr 1st step = 0x18e007fc0 //Wrong
Addr 2nd step = 0x8e007fc0
*/
```

Comment: You should use `uint64_t` from `stdint.h` instead of inventing your own.

Comment: You declared it unsigned -- this means if you use a sign there will be many interesting effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`u_int32` is unsigned. The negative `360` that you assigned to it gets re-interpreted as a positive 32-bit number. When you add it to `u_int64`, the value **gets extended with 32 zeros** to match the size of the other operand. This is not what you wanted: since the number was negative, you need all ones in the upper half in order for the addition to produce the desired effect after the result of the addition is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by `u_int64`<sup>*</sup>.

If you declare the `num` as `u_int64`, the first and the second parts produce the expected number ([demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/MOWO3)).

```
u_int64 baseAddr = 0x8e008128;
u_int64 num = -360;
u_int64 addr = baseAddr + num; // Works!
printf("\nAddr 1st step = 0x%llx\n", addr);
```

---

<sup>*</sup> 6.2.5 (9) "A computation involving unsigned operands can never overﬂow, because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type.". Thanks, [Daniel Fischer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011995/daniel-fischer) for finding the relevant portion of the standard!

Comment: The conversion to unsigned integer types is completely defined. Using `u_int64 num = -360;` is guaranteed to produce the desired result in all conforming implementations.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am talking about the effect of `baseAddr + num` when the result of the addition uses more than 64 bits.

Comment: That is also completely defined, since the types are unsigned.

Comment: In N1570, it's 6.2.5 (9) "A computation involving unsigned operands can never overﬂow, because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type."

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for referencing the standard! I did not realize that unsigned additions that ignore the carry bit are well-defined in C.

Comment: You're welcome. I often depend on that, it's quite a useful thing (I wish we had that guarantee also for signed integers).

Answer (score 4):

`u_int32` is an unsigned type; assigning -360 to it will cause integer overflow and result in `num` holding a very large positive value.

Comment: It's technically not overflow, computations on unsigned integers don't overflow. The conversion to unsigned types (and of results of unsigned computations whose mathematical result is not representable in the type) is specified by the standard to be reduction modulo `2^N` (where `N` is the width of the unsigned type), so the value will be `2^32 - 360`.

Comment: I guess I'm calling it overflow in the colloquial sense, then :)

Comment: I often do that too. I just thought it should be mentioned.